# Determinant line of Fredholm operators and composition of morphisms

Tags: ct.category-theory, determinants, index-theory, fredholm-operators

Let $P$ be a polarization of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, i.e. a bounded idempotent: consider a group $G=GL_{res}(\mathcal{H}):=\{g \in GL(\mathcal{H}): [g,P] \in HS\}$ (where $HS$ is the set of all Hilbert Schmidt operators). For $g \in G$ let $P_g:=gPg^{-1}$ and define $F_{g,h}=P_gP_h-P_h+I$. One can check that $F_{g,h}$ are Fredholm: therefore one can define the so called *determinant line* $det(F_{g,h})$ to be $\Lambda^{top}(ker(F_{g,h})) \otimes \Lambda^{top}(coker(F_{g,h}))^*$. Using this data one can construct a (small) category where (the set of) objects is $G$ and for $g,h \in G$ we put $Hom(g,h)=det(F_{g,h})$. However it is not immediate that this constitutes a category: in order to do so one have to prove some identifications:

> How to prove that $det(F_{g,h} \cdot F_{h,k}) \cong det(F_{g,h}) \otimes det(F_{h,k})$?

Of course both spaces are in fact one dimensional therefore there is an *abstract* isomorphism but I suspect that this isomorphism should be somehow *canonical* and natural. I would guess that in order to construct such an isomorphism maybe one has to use the fact that $Index(F_{g,h}F_{h,k})=Index(F_{g,h})+Index(F_{h,k})$.

Once we have this identification one can show that in fact $F_{g,h}F_{h,k}-F_{g,k}$ is a trace-class operator.

> How to prove that if $S,T$ are two Fredholm operators with $S-T$ being trace-class then $detS \cong detT$ are *canonically* isomorphic?

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: It is not exactly this, but there is a discussion about something similar in abbondandolo and majer’s paper infinite dimensional grassmannians

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I think that one can deduce the first part from this paper-still I'm also interested in the second part (if a difference $S-T$ is trace class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the first part of the question is in Abbonandolo and Majers "Infinite dimensional Grassmannians". My Hilbert spaces are real and separable and infinite dimensional.

I want to state that I basically know next to nothing about trace class operators, so take the rest with a grain of salt.

To every Fredholm operator one can associate its determinant line. An important fact is that this defines an actual line *bundle* over the space of Fredholm operators $\mathrm{det}\rightarrow \Phi(\mathbb{H})$. This is the unique (up to isomorphism) line bundle over $\Phi(\mathbb{H})$ that is non-trivial over each component of $\Phi(\mathbb{H})$. (This uses the fact that all components are homotopy equivalent and that $\pi_1(\Phi(\mathbb H))\cong\mathbb{Z}/2)$.

A continuous family of Fredholm operators is a continuous map $f:X\rightarrow \Phi(\mathbb H)$. One can use this map to pull back the determinant line bundle over $X$. Let's assume that $X$ is connected. Then the bundle $f^*\det$ is a trivial bundle over $X$ if and only if $f_*:\pi_1(X)\rightarrow \pi_1(\Phi(\mathbb H))$ is the trivial homomorphism.

Let $S$ be a Fredholm operator. Let $X$ be the space of Fredholm operators T such that $S-T$ is trace class, and $f:X\rightarrow \Phi(\mathbb H)$ the inclusion. I think that $X$ is an affine space, hence contractible, from which it follows that $f_*$ is trivial. This means that the determinant line bundle is trivial over $X$. You can use the triviality of the determinant line bundle to give a canonical isomorphism between two different operators of trace class.

Comment: Thank you, it sounds reasonable! I assume that you have meant $X$ to be _convex_ instead of affine space, right?

Comment: Convex is fine as well, but Isnt X affine? (But maybe we have different definitions of affine in mind)

Comment: I should say that this only gives an iso up to homotopy if you dont have a metric on the determinant line bundle. But i believe quillen also constructed such a metric. But i dont know the details

Comment: Why do you need a metric? I though that if $\pi_1(X)$ is itrivial then so is $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ the latter being isomorphic to rank one real vector bundles. Also, I'm wondering about the following: as far as I know, one really needs the difference to be a _trace class_ (not merely Hilbert-Schmidt for example)-but your proof seems to work if we replace trace class operators by Hilbert-Schmidt so I;m a little bit worried whether everything is all right

Comment: Dear @truebaran: It is true that the triviality of the vector bundle does not depend on the metric. However, to do parallel transport from one fiber to another we need to choose a metric I think.

Comment: Still I'm not quite convinced: once your bundle is trivial you can take this existing isomorphism and that allows you to canonically identify all the fibers. Also, I'm wondering where your proof does not work if we replace _trace class_ operators by _Hilbert-Schmidt_? Somehow in this broader context (Hilbert-Schmidt) you are not allowed to identify but your proof seems to work fine: so I'm not sure whether something is missing there